# DB suggestion to connect with Gremlin.Net API

Tags: nosql, graph-databases

I have been trying to install and run Cosmos DB emulator to create graphs using Gremlin.Net. However I failed to run it successfully, because there were many problems to connect to it. Then I installed Tinkerpop Apache Gremlin Server and Console to connect to Gremlin.Net. However I have come to know that Tinkerpop Gremlin Server keeps data in memory (Pardon me if I have wrongly understood it because I am crazily doing things because of short timeline)

I want to ask if there is any other better DB to connect to, which can keep data permanently instead of in-memory.

Please keep in mind I have to use Gremlin.Net API because the deployment will be done on Azure using Cosmos DB.

I am very new to Graph databases so getting in troubles while working with Graph DBs.